# Regex PHP find 2 words same position

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to apply a regex to find the English month when i search for the month string in Spanish or other idiom. Currently i have an array of possible matches:

```
$monthsIdioms = array(
                'en' => array('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'),    
'es' => array(
            '/ene/',
            '/feb/',
            '/mar/',
            '/abr/',
            '/may/',
            '/jun/',
            '/jul/',
            '/ago/',
            '/sep/',
            '/oct/',
            '/nov/',
            '/dic/'
        ));
```

But my date variable can have this format:

```
$date = "24 ene 15:45";
```

Or this one:

```
$date = "24 enero 15:45";
```

So i need a regex to find ene or enero in my date and with the other months:

```
'es' => array(
                    '/ene|enero/',
                    '/feb|febrero/',
                    '/mar|marzo/',
                    '/abr|abril/',
                    '/may|mayo/',
                    '/jun|junio/',
                    '/jul|julio/',
                    '/ago|agosto/',
                    '/set|septiembre/',
                    '/oct|octubre/',
                    '/nov|noviembre/',
                    '/dic|diciembre/'
                )
```

And i call this with:

```
preg_replace($monthsIdioms['es'], $monthsIdioms['en'], $date);
```

but regex | is not properly working. What i am dong wrong?

Note that 'es' array is regex strings.

**So to clarify this, i want that if i have this date: "24 ene 15:45" or this: "24 enero 15:45" to get converted to: "24 jan 15:45" the same with with any other month of the year: "24 ago 15:45" or "24 agosto 15:45" to "24 aug 15:45".**

Comment: could this question not be reduced to: why does this not work?: `preg_replace('/ene|enero/', 'jan', $date);`

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what do you want it to look like? Perhaps some sample data? One thing I see off the top is you would want to flip the short/long names to be `long|short` because the regex will see `ene` and stop searching.

Comment: Also, what seems to be the problem (aside from what I said above)? "Not working" doesn't really help much. What isn't working? Also, [looks fine to me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ifGo7O).

Comment: You're right @hoijui, that is the question. I want to translate: `24 ene 15:45` or `24 enero 15:45` to `24 jan 15:45` but all the year too: `24 ago 15:45` or `24 agosto 15:45` to `24 aug 15:45`

Comment: Still not seeing the issue here aside from having to swap the long/short values: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OAxYxS. Edit: Here, swapped them: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AYjB2g

Comment: @walolinux if the question can be reduced to what i said, then please edit it and reduce it. this saves others the time for reading irrelevant info, and parsing out what is relevant, and it makes the question more general, potentially helping more other people.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn replace ene to enero and ago to agosto: (http://codepad.viper-7.com/FO6ffs) output is not OK.

Comment: I've said 3 times now, swap the long name and short name so the pattern is `long|short`. Or for example: 'enero|ene'. If you don't, the regex engine will match up to the first possible match it can find which is `ene` and stop after that. Here is a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bbf8Qp

Comment: To be a little more complete, the pattern should be more like: `/\b(enero|ene)\b/i`. That will find only whole word (no partial matches like `ene` in `enero` and it is case insensitive. Adding the `\b` will force the string to not match `ene` when part of `enero`. If later you want to add more to the possible list, you can add them inside the parenthesis like: `/\b(ene|enero|whatever|foo|bar)\b/i`.

Answer (score 0):

Well since all short names of the month are inside the actual name of the month you could just add a space:

```
'en' => array('jan ', 'feb ', 'mar ', 'etc'),
'es' => array('/ene |enero /','/feb |febrero /','/mar |marzo / ','etc')
```